# Cogenerators in a triangulated category

Tags: rt.representation-theory, triangulated-categories

Let $\mathscr{T}$ be a triangulated category and $[1]$ be the shift functor in $\mathscr{T}$ and $X\in \mathscr{T}$ be a cogenerator i.e. if $Hom(Y,X[i])=0,i\in\mathbb{Z}$, then we have $Y=0$. My question is, assume $f:M\to N$ is a morphism and $Hom(f,X[i])=0,i\in\mathbb{Z}$, then do we have $f=0$ in this case? Here $Hom(f,X): Hom(N,X)\to Hom(M,X)$ is induced by $f$.

Comment: What is $X[i]$? The definition of a [cogenerator](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cogenerator) I'm familiar with doesn't use $\mathbb{Z}$ anywhere; is this a special case of the notion of a cogenerator in a triangulated category? Further, what is your definition of the Hom -set between an arrow and an object? Something to do with a slice category?

Comment: I’m sorry, I have updated the question。And here I use cogenerator the meaning in the question and maybe this is a special definition as you said。

Comment: There are examples where the answer to the corresponding question with generators is no (these are called "ghost maps" in classical stable homotopy theory). So can you just take the opposite category in such a situation?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri thank you for your help。